# How does Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat) format the data?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, byte

I have a non transparent, colour bitmap with length 2480 and width 3507.

Using `Bitmap.GetPixel(int x, int y)` I am able to get the colour information of each pixel in the bitmap.

If I squirt the bitmap into a byte[]:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
ms.Position = 0;
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

then I'd expect to have the same information, i.e. I can go to bytes[1000] and read the colour information for that pixel.

It turns out that my array of bytes is larger than I anticipated. I thought I'd get an array with 2480 x 3507 = 8697360 elements. Instead I get an array with 8698438 elements - some sort of header I presume.

In what format the bytes in my array stored? Is there a header 1078 bytes long followed by Alpha, Red, Green, Blue values for every byte element, or something else?

All I need is the colour information for each pixel. I'm not concerned with the header (or indeed the transparency) unless I need it to get the colour info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `GetBuffer` which returns the underlying byte array - that's bigger than the actual length of the stream.

*Either* use

```
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

*or* use `GetBuffer` but in conjunction with `ms.Length`.

Having said that, you're saving it as a BMP - so there'll be header information as well; it's not like the first byte will represent the first pixel. Unfortunately there's no "raw" image format as far as I can see... that's what it sounds like you really want.

You could use [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=VS.90).aspx) and then copy the data from there, if you want...

Comment: I've changed my code to get the array but I'm still getting the same number of bytes (I guess I was lucky with my MemoryStream)

Comment: Thanks, Lockbits is what I need. I think http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm will help get me where I need to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the documentation about `Bitmap.Save`, it saves the image in the specified format, which means that you'll have in your bytes array, the bitmap header. I think you should read some documentation about the [bitmap format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_bitmap) to know how to get the needed information in your array