# VuDroid pdf viewer cannot find Bitmap to render or it doesnt render

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, pdf-viewer, vudroid

I am trying to use the [VuDroid](http://code.google.com/p/vudroid/source/browse/#svn/trunk) PDF viewer and I need to take the rendered bitmap and store it as a byte[]. Then I need to convert it back into a Bitmap that can be displayed on a view using something like "canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);".

I have spent many hours trying to access the Bitmap and I might have done it already, but even if I get the byte[] to return something it still wont render as a Bitmap on the canvas.

Could someone please help me here, I must be missing something. Thank you so much.

I believe it is supposed to accessed via...

PDFPage.java .... public Bitmap renderBitmap(int width, int height, RectF pageSliceBounds)

-or-

through Page.java -or- DocumentView.java -or- DecodeService.java

Like I said I have tried all of these and have gotten results I just cannot see where I am going wrong since I cannot render it to see if the Bitmap was called correctly.

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

The doc says the method returns "null if the image could not be decode." You can try:

```
byte[] image = services.getImageBuffer(1024, 600);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

I think This will help you:-

[Render a byte[] as Bitmap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683694/render-a-byte-as-bitmap-in-android)

[How does Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat) format the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591705/how-does-bitmap-savestream-imageformat-format-the-data)

[Copy image with alpha channel to clipboard with custom background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785909/copy-image-with-alpha-channel-to-clipboard-with-custom-background-color)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get each pdf page as independent bitmap you should consider that 
 **VuDroid** render the pages, 
 **PDFView** only display them.
you should use VuDroid functions.

now you can use this example and create your own codes

**Example code : for make bitmap from a specific PDF page**

```
    view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    pdf_conext = new PdfContext();
    PdfDocument d = pdf_conext.openDocument(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "your PDF path");

    PdfPage vuPage = d.getPage(1); // choose your page number
    RectF rf = new RectF();
    rf.bottom = rf.right = (float)1.0;
    Bitmap bitmap = vuPage.renderBitmap(60, 60, rf); //define width and height of bitmap

    view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**for  writing this bitmap on SDCARD** :

```
try {   
    File mediaImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "your path for save thumbnail images ");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mediaImage);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**for retrieve saved image**:

```
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "your path for save thumbnail images ");

        String path = file.getAbsolutePath(); 
        if (path != null){
            view = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path), YOUR_X, YOUR_Y, false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code to check whether bitmap is properly generating or not

PdfContext pdf_conext = new PdfContext();
PdfDocument d = (PdfDocument) pdf_conext.openDocument(pdfPath);  

PdfPage vuPage = (PdfPage) d.getPage(0);  
RectF rf = new RectF();  

Bitmap bitmap = vuPage.renderBitmap(1000,600, rf);  

File dir1 = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/IMAGES");
dir1.mkdirs();
String fname = "Image-"+ 2 +".jpg";
File file = new File (dir1, fname);
if (file.exists ()) 
file.delete (); 
try {
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
     out.flush();
     out.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {

 e.printStackTrace();

}
```